# A question on group extensions

Tags: group-theory, group-extensions

Let $N=\langle x_1, \ldots, x_m; \mathbf{r}\rangle$ and $H=\langle y_1, \ldots, y_n; \mathbf{s}\rangle$ ($m$ and $n$ can be infinite). Then if we define,

$G=\langle x_1, \ldots, y_1, \ldots; \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{s}, x_i^{y_j}=x_i\phi_j\rangle$

where $\phi_j\in Aut(N)$ for all $j=1, \ldots, n$ we get a short exact sequence, $$1\rightarrow \overline{N}\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow 1$$ where $\overline{N}=\langle x_1, \ldots, x_m\rangle$.

(Basically, pin two groups together via an automorphism of one of them.)

My questions are these:

> -Is it true that $\overline{N}\cong N$ ?
>
> -If $\overline{N}\cong N$, does it hold that $G=N\rtimes H$ ?
>
> -Do the above two questions hold if we stipulate that the $\phi_j$ arise in the natural way from a map $\langle y_1, \ldots, y_n\rangle\rightarrow Aut(N)?$

If these do not hold, does anyone know of a reference which explores when they do or do not?

Comment: It only works if the $\phi_j$ are "functorial"; that is, you need $\phi_i\circ\phi_j$ to reflect the product $y_iy_j$ (composition of functions left to right). Otherwise, you don't. E.g., if $y_i^n=e$, say, and $\phi_i^n\neq \mathrm{id}$, then you get $x_j = (x_j)\phi^n_j$ in $\overline{N}$, and you know that those equalities cannot all hold in $N$ if $\phi_i^n\neq\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: Arturo: I suppose that is conceivable that the answer to the first question could be yes, even if the $\phi_j$ are not functorial, if $N$ was a nonHopfian group?

Comment: @Swlabr: In that case, the answer to both is "yes"; essentially, an internal semidirect product is equivalent to an external one, and an external one is equivalent to a homomorphism $H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll re-edit my question to remove my previous edit, so your answer makes sense. Alternatively, this will just confuse everyone, but hey...

Comment: @Swlabr: How about *adding* the condition below the original question?

Comment: Ah, yes, good idea. My brain is not working at full speed today...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple counterexample, given the requirements specified. Take $N=C_3 = \langle x|x^3\rangle$, the cyclic group of order $3$, and let $H=C_5 = \langle y|y^5\rangle$, the cyclic group of order $5$. Let $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ be the nontrivial automorphism. You then have
$$G = \langle x,y\mid x^3,y^5, x^y=x^2\rangle.$$

We then have $x^{y^2} = x$, so $x^{y^4}=x$, hence $x = x^1 = x^{y^5} = (x^{y^4})^y = x^y = x^2$. Thus, $x=1$ in $G$, So $\overline{N}$ is trivial.

The problem is that the assignment $\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}\to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$ is not being asked to "reflect" the relations $\mathbf{s}$, so that forces new relation on the $x_i$. In order to get the isomorphisms, you need the assignment $y_i\mapsto \phi_i$ (which induces a group homomorphism from the free group in the $y_i$ into $\mathrm{Aut}(N)$) to factor through $H$; i.e., you really need a group homomorphism $H\to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$, not just an assignment of the generators to homomorphisms.

**If** you have a homomorphism $H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$, then the answer to both question is "yes". An "external semidirect product of $N$ by $H$" is equivalent to a homomorphism $H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$ (see, e.g., Exercise I.12.12 in Lang's *Algebra*, or the section on semidirect products (pages 167-171, especially Lemmas 7.20 and 7.21, and Theorems 7.22 and 7.23 in Rotman's *Introduction to the Theory of Groups*, 4th Edition), and the presentation of the semidirect product is the one you give.

If, as it happens, you have that $\overline{N}\cong N$, then the answer to your second question is "yes". Note that we certainly have $\overline{N}\triangleleft G$, there is a generating set $S$ such that $x^{-1}Nx = N$ for all $x\in S$, namely $S=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots y_m\}$. Also, $G/\overline{N} \cong \langle y_1,\ldots,y_m,\mathbf{s}\rangle\cong H$, as that's the presentation we get if we add the conditions $x_i=1$, $i=1,\ldots,n$. So $\overline{N}\triangleleft G$, and $G/\overline{N}\cong H$ with $\langle y_1,\ldots,y_m\rangle\cong H$ in $G$, so $G\cong \overline{N}\rtimes H$. Since we are assuming that $\overline{N}\cong N$, you certainly get *a* semidirect product $G\cong N\rtimes H$. **However,** it need not be given by the action of $H$ on $N$ given by the $\phi_i$: you would need to conjugate that action with the isomorphism $\psi\colon\overline{N}\to N$.

Comment: Hi - yes, sorry I had meant to stipulate this when asking the question. I'll edit it just now.

Answer (score 4):

Just to turn Arturo's comment into an answer to the question, if the assignment $y_j \mapsto \phi_j$ extends to a homomorphism $\phi: H \rightarrow {\rm Aut}(N)$ (which is the case if and only if the $\phi_j$ satisfy the relations of $H$ when substituted for $y_j$), then the answer to both questions is yes. (I think the answer to the second question is always yes.)